# AS3- Is it possible to call a variable from a string?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to make "getDefinitionByName()" work with any Object type, I have only gotten it to work with a Class:

```
 var test:Class = getDefinitionByName("myClass") as Class;
```

I need something like:

```
var myNumber:Number = 10; 
var test:Number = getDefinitionByName("myNumber") as Number;

trace(test); //10
```

Or is there another method to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define your key codes as public **static** constants in your KeyCodes class:

```
class KeyCodes { 
    public static const A:int = 65;
}
```

You can then use them as arguments to your `useKeyCodes` function:

```
useKeyCodes(KeyCodes.A);
```

This way you get the benefit of not having to remember every key code.

Comment: This is a solution. Actually, one of things, why the constants themselves were invented, is to identify literal values like PI or KEY_UP etc, so you don't need to remember it's value - just constant name. And for keycodes there's a class 'Key' (read more in manual).

Answer (score 1):

No.

That's the short answer, getDefinitionByName gets the class definition. You can access public fields and function with the [] syntax, as in `trace(this["myNumber"]);`. You example seems to be with a local variable which really does not really make sense.

Perhaps you can explain what you want to do, this sounds like something you can design you way out of.

Comment: I have a keycode class which is full of keyCode integers, I want to be able to access them from another class, by using a string. 

class keyCodes { public const A:int = 65; } 

class myClass { 

function useKeyCodes(key:String){ 

var keyCode:int = keyCodes.getDefinitionByName(key) as int; 

} 

} 

I want to be able to add new keys for the keyboard event listener without thinking about key codes

Comment: Use this: obj.useKeyCodes(flash.ui.Keyboard.A);